# Vue approach to populating components

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vue-component

I can't seem to find any information how it would be best to put data inside a component. To define the problem, lets say we have a `user` table in a database and this table has an ID and maybe 30 fields with details about the user.

Now if I want to create a Vue component that shows a list of many users details, lets just call it `<user-details>`. To show this on a page, would you:

1) Call the database to get all users you want to show and get their ID, then do a for loop with `<user-details id="xxx">` and make Vue do ajax call to some API and get the details?

2) OR, use the inline version `<user-details id="xxx" name="user name" ...>` with 30+ fields?

3) OR, have some specific Vue component for this user list, maybe it's users who did not validate email or something, then `<users-not-validated>` and use ajax?

The problem I see is, that in case 1, you already called the database for the IDs, then call the database once again with ajax with pretty much the same SQL.

In case 2, it's just annoying to fill so many fields out each time you use the component.

In case 3, you will end up with a TON of components...

How do you approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find such information because it's not Vue related. Vue doesn't care what you use it for and how you structure your data. It aims to allow you to do anything you want.

Just as it doesn't care what your folder structure looks like (because, at its core, all it needs in order to render is a single DOM element), it also doesn't care how you organize your API, how you structure your application, your pages or even your components.

Obviously, having this amount of freedom is not always a good thing. If you look around, you'll notice people who use Vue professionally have embraced certain patterns/structures which allow for better code reuse and more flexibility. Nuxt is one such good example.

To anyone just starting with Vue, I recommend trying to use Nuxt as soon as possible, even if its overkill for their little project because they will likely pick up some good patterns.

---

Getting down to your specific question, in terms of data API architecture, you always have to ask yourself: what's the underlying principle?

The underlying principle is to make your application as fast as possible. In order to do that, ideally, you want to fetch exactly how much data you want to display, but not more. Therefore:

- when getting the same data, if you have a choice, always try to lower the number of requests. You don't want each item in the list to initiate a call to the server when it is rendered. Make a single call for the entire list (only fetching what you display in the list view) and call for details if the user requests it (presses the details button).
- adjust your pagination to cater how many items you can display on a screen, but also according to how long it takes to load a page. If it takes too long, lower the pageSize and allow your items more padding. If you think about it, most people prefer a snappy app with fewer items on page (and generously padded items) to one which takes seconds to load each page and displays items so crummed they're hard to click/tap on or hard to follow in the list without losing the row.

However, you have to take these guidelines with a grain of salt. In the vast majority of cases fetching full data in one call makes little to no difference in user experience. Many times the delays have to do with server cold-starts (first call to a server takes longer, as it needs to "wake it up" - but all subsequent calls of the same type are faster), with unoptimized images or with bad internet connectivity (as in, it works poorly regardless of whether you receive only the names or the full list of details).

Another aspect to keep in mind is that getting all the data at once is a trade-off. You do get a slower initial call but afterwards you are able to do seamless animations between list view and detail view as the data is already fetched, no more loading required. If you handle the loading state graciously, it's a viable option in many scenarios.

---

Last, but not least, your 2nd point's drawback does not exist. You can always bind all the details in one go:

```
<user-details v-bind="user" />
```

is equivalent to

```
<user-details :id="user.id" :name="user.name" :age="user.age" ... />
```

---

To give you a very basic example, the typical markup for your use-case would be:

```
<div v-if="isLoadingUsers" />
<user-list v-else :users="users">
   <user-list-item v-for="(user, key) in users"
                   :key="key"
                   v-bind="user" 
                   @click="selectedUser = user" />
</user-list>
<user-details-modal v-bind="selectedUser" />
```

It's obviously a simplification, you might opt to not have a user details modal but a cool `transform` on the list item, making it grow and display more details, etc...

When in doubt, simplify. For example, only showing details for one selected item (and closing it when selecting another) will solve a lot of UI problems right off the bat.

---

As for the last question: whether or not to have different components for different states, the answer should come from answering a different question: how large should you allow your component to get? The upper limit is generally considered around 300 lines, although I know developers who don't go above 200 and others who don't have a problem having 500+ lines in a component).

When it becomes too large, you should extract a part of it (let's say the user-not-validated functionality into a sub-component) and end up with this inside the `<user-detail>` component:

```
<user-detail>
  ... common details (title, description, etc...)

  <div v-if="user.isValidated">
     ...normal case
  </div>
  <user-not-validated v-bind="user" v-else />

  ... common functionality (action bar, etc...)
</user-detail>
```

But, these are sub-components of your `<user-detail>` component, which are extracted to help you keep the code organized. They shouldn't replace `<user-detail>` in its entirety. Similarly, you could extract the user-detail header or footer components, whatever makes sense. Your goal should be to keep your code neat and organized. Follow whatever principles make more sense to you.

---

Finally, if I had to single out one helpful guideline when taking code architecture decisions, it would definitely be the DRY principle. If you end up not having to write the same code in multiple places in the same application, you're doing it right.

Hope you'll find some of the above useful.